# Редактирование информации на этапе жизненного цикла onMounted компонета в Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: vue3

Изучаю VUE 3.
На этапе монтирования, после получения данных с сервера решил изменить данные:

```
<script setup>
...
const Task = ref([])
...
onMounted(() => {
    idTask.value = props.id
    axios
        .get("/tasks/" + idTask.value)
        .then(res => {
            Task.value = res.data
        })
    if (Task.value['description'] === '')
        Task.value['description'] = 'Введите текст описания задачи'
...
```

Однако оказалось что Task.value['description'] на этом этапе имеет значение `undefined`

Использовал хук жизненного цикла onBeforeUpdate для проверки. Доступ к переменной есть. Значение выводится.Наверняка и менять можно.

```
onBeforeUpdate (() => {
    console.log(Task.value['description'])
    }
```

**Вопрос в следующем:**
На этапе монтирования не положено изменять данные? Или я не нашёл как это сделать?

Comment: У вас axios - а он Async, то есть ваш If "спрашивает" то , чего пока еще нет. Поставьте его в .then после присвоения результата.